# Multiple SSL on Single IP

Tags: 12.04, ssl

I would like to host multiple sites at Ubuntu 12.04 where each one use separate SSL certificate.

I have configured virtualhost for each website with different document root in default_ssl.conf but it works only first one virtual host.

Comment: This is possible but it is hard to tell what you did wrong with only these sparse information. I suggest you check your configuration again and make sure it matches documented setups (like [here](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm)) and if you still need help better ask at serverfault.com.

Comment: This method has already been applied but it did't work. I many need to check some configuration regarding support of SNI. Can you help in this regard?

Comment: What part of "...and if you still need help better ask at serverfault.com." is hard to understand?

Comment: You need to configure SNI: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm, https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: Have configured already but it execute only first virtualhost.

Comment: I suggest to post your configuration file, maybe someone could see some error that you didn't see. Use http://pastebin.com/ and update your question with url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding server aliases, both the virtualhost are working fine now.